# A printer that doesn't protest refilled cartridges?

Tags: printer

My HP Photosmart B110a worked fine the first couple of times I refilled the cartridges. Now it has given up with an error.

Is there a printer on the market which will accept refilled cartridges?

Comment: I donno. Having messed around with refilling printers in the past, printers range from "No, Original ink only" to "This is totally going to void your warranty. You pinky swear you're sure?" to "I have no idea how much ink there is so I'll print anyway" to "Meh. FEED ME. FEEEEED ME!". Its a very practical requirement.

Answer (score 7):

Epson has a line of printers *specifically* designed to be refilled - called the ecotank/supertank line - they're a bit pricier than 'regular' printers (which are absurdly cheap cause they're selling you the ink at a markup) but they are essentially CIS printers with external ink tanks. Since you arn't popping out a tank designed to slowly drip ink, its a lot neater, and it dosen't have the abitrary pages per cart count most printers would have.

There's a bunch of models - the [l310](https://www.epson.eu/ix/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/overview/15802) seems to be the basic model but the [US seems to have a different lineup](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Landing/ecotank-super-tank-printers.do) with all of them being all in ones